# javascript catch comet socket disconnect

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I have implemented comet sockets on my server, and am able to push data to the browser fine. But what I would like to do is catch in javascript/jquery when the comet server drops out.

I have my iframe:

```
<div id="iframeDiv" style="visibility:hidden; height:0px">
    <iframe id="comet" src="/messageSocket?-3711886712169888393"></iframe>
</div>
```

and i have my javascript to handle the new message:

```
// Comet Server Processes actions
var messageReceived = function(message) {
var commandType = message[1];
switch (commandType) {
    case "1":
        processActionData(message);
        break;
    ...
    default:
        break;
}

}
```

but for example lets say the connection drops for whatever reason? How can I bring it back up? For example if the local server hosting the website shuts down and starts back up again I would like on the client to catch a timeout? And then reload the page. How do I do this? Do I need to create a loops that makes an ajax ping requests to determine if the connection is still alive? Is there a better way to just catch when the comet socket dies?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how the comet protocol works exactly, but one thing you can do is send a ping message every couple seconds. If the server doesn't send a ping in, idk, 10 seconds, you assume the server dropped the connection.

I've used this method in a client-server application before.

Comment: Thanks bobby I have read this before, atm I think this is my best bet as I haven't found any other possible solutions. I was just hoping there was an onDisconnect, or something similar.

Comment: Your welcome :) And there may be an onDisconnect-type event, but, as I said, I haven't used comet (except for socket.io which uses it internally)

Comment: I implemented this today and the problem I have is that the ping request from the client is ajax. And I am just wondering how to handle the situation when the ping request succeeds but the comet socket/forever iframe stops?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean, but if either ping doesn't work, you  assume the connection is down (in a practical example you might wanna try again)

Comment: I guess the issue with ping is if i check every 4 seconds, the site goes down, then back up again within 4 seconds well the ping will always succeed but the comet socket will be dropped.

Comment: I'm not sure how to help you there, sorry.